# UE4 Package Fails When Any Non-Default Plugin is Enabled

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, deployment, unreal-engine4

When I enable 'Mobile Location Services - iOS Implementation' I can't launch my game on my phone. 
And It was working fine before. I don't get why!!!

My MacBook Pro version Is 10.13.2

I am using Unreal Engine 4.18.2

I have an iPhone 7 with version 11.2.1

I'm using xCode Version 9.2.

Can someone who develops iOS games and uses at least one non-default plugin send me their specs???
I mean the versions of UE4, Xcode, Mac and iPhone.

Please helpppp:( I have a deadline soon...

Here are the error lines,

```
LogPlayLevel: ********** BUILD COMMAND STARTED **********
LogPlayLevel: Completed Launch On Stage: Build Task, Time: 29.701877
LogPlayLevel: Running: mono "/Users/Shared/Epic Games/UE_4.18/Engine/Binaries/DotNET/UnrealBuildTool.exe" TamagotchiGame IOS Development -Project="/Users/bariscavusoglu/Documents/Unreal Projects/TamagotchiGame/TamagotchiGame.uproject"  "/Users/bariscavusoglu/Documents/Unreal Projects/TamagotchiGame/TamagotchiGame.uproject" -NoUBTMakefiles  -remoteini="/Users
/bariscavusoglu/Documents/Unreal Projects/TamagotchiGame" -skipdeploy -ini:Game:[/Script/UnrealEd.ProjectPackagingSettings]:BlueprintNativizationMethod=Disabled -noxge -generatemanifest -nocreatestub -NoHotReload
LogPlayLevel:   Compiling with iPhoneOS SDK 11.2
LogPlayLevel: Took 39.025591s to run mono, ExitCode=0
LogPlayLevel: Running: mono "/Users/Shared/Epic Games/UE_4.18/Engine/Binaries/DotNET/UnrealBuildTool.exe" TamagotchiGame IOS Development -Project="/Users/bariscavusoglu/Documents/Unreal Projects/TamagotchiGame/TamagotchiGame.uproject"  "/Users/bariscavusoglu/Documents/Unreal Projects/TamagotchiGame/TamagotchiGame.uproject" -NoUBTMakefiles  -remoteini="/Users
/bariscavusoglu/Documents/Unreal Projects/TamagotchiGame" -skipdeploy -ini:Game:[/Script/UnrealEd.ProjectPackagingSettings]:BlueprintNativizationMethod=Disabled -noxge -nocreatestub -NoHotReload -ignorejunk
LogPlayLevel:   Compiling with iPhoneOS SDK 11.2
LogPlayLevel:   Performing 3 actions (8 in parallel)
LogPlayLevel:   [1/3] Compile UELinkerFixups.cpp
LogPlayLevel:   [2/3] sh /Users/bariscavusoglu/Documents/Unreal Projects/TamagotchiGame/Binaries/IOS/TamagotchiGame
LogPlayLevel:   [3/3] xcrun  actool --output-format human-readable-text --notices --warnings --output-partial-info-plist "/Users/bariscavusoglu/Documents/Unreal Projects/TamagotchiGame/Intermediate/IOS/Resources/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist" --app-icon AppIcon --enable-on-demand-resources YES --target-device iphone --target-device ipad --minimum-deploym
ent-target 9.0 --platform iphoneos --product-type com.apple.product-type.application --compile "/Users/bariscavusoglu/Documents/Unreal Projects/TamagotchiGame/Binaries/IOS/Payload/TamagotchiGame.app" "/Users/bariscavusoglu/Documents/Unreal Projects/TamagotchiGame/Intermediate/IOS/Resources/Assets.xcassets"
LogPlayLevel:   /* com.apple.actool.document.notices */
LogPlayLevel:   /Users/bariscavusoglu/Documents/Unreal Projects/TamagotchiGame/Intermediate/IOS/Resources/Assets.xcassets:./AppIcon.appiconset/[][ipad][76x76][][][1x][][]: notice: 76x76@1x app icons only apply to iPad apps targeting releases of iOS prior to 10.0.
LogPlayLevel:   /* com.apple.actool.compilation-results */
LogPlayLevel:   /Users/bariscavusoglu/Documents/Unreal Projects/TamagotchiGame/Binaries/IOS/Payload/TamagotchiGame.app/AppIcon20x20@2x.png
LogPlayLevel:   /Users/bariscavusoglu/Documents/Unreal Projects/TamagotchiGame/Binaries/IOS/Payload/TamagotchiGame.app/AppIcon20x20@3x.png
LogPlayLevel:   /Users/bariscavusoglu/Documents/Unreal Projects/TamagotchiGame/Binaries/IOS/Payload/TamagotchiGame.app/AppIcon29x29@2x.png
LogPlayLevel:   /Users/bariscavusoglu/Documents/Unreal Projects/TamagotchiGame/Binaries/IOS/Payload/TamagotchiGame.app/AppIcon29x29@3x.png
LogPlayLevel:   /Users/bariscavusoglu/Documents/Unreal Projects/TamagotchiGame/Binaries/IOS/Payload/TamagotchiGame.app/AppIcon40x40@2x.png
LogPlayLevel:   /Users/bariscavusoglu/Documents/Unreal Projects/TamagotchiGame/Binaries/IOS/Payload/TamagotchiGame.app/AppIcon40x40@3x.png
LogPlayLevel:   /Users/bariscavusoglu/Documents/Unreal Projects/TamagotchiGame/Binaries/IOS/Payload/TamagotchiGame.app/AppIcon60x60@2x.png
LogPlayLevel:   /Users/bariscavusoglu/Documents/Unreal Projects/TamagotchiGame/Binaries/IOS/Payload/TamagotchiGame.app/AppIcon60x60@3x.png
LogPlayLevel:   /Users/bariscavusoglu/Documents/Unreal Projects/TamagotchiGame/Binaries/IOS/Payload/TamagotchiGame.app/AppIcon20x20~ipad.png
LogPlayLevel:   /Users/bariscavusoglu/Documents/Unreal Projects/TamagotchiGame/Binaries/IOS/Payload/TamagotchiGame.app/AppIcon20x20@2x~ipad.png
LogPlayLevel:   /Users/bariscavusoglu/Documents/Unreal Projects/TamagotchiGame/Binaries/IOS/Payload/TamagotchiGame.app/AppIcon29x29~ipad.png
LogPlayLevel:   /Users/bariscavusoglu/Documents/Unreal Projects/TamagotchiGame/Binaries/IOS/Payload/TamagotchiGame.app/AppIcon29x29@2x~ipad.png
LogPlayLevel:   /Users/bariscavusoglu/Documents/Unreal Projects/TamagotchiGame/Binaries/IOS/Payload/TamagotchiGame.app/AppIcon40x40~ipad.png
LogPlayLevel:   /Users/bariscavusoglu/Documents/Unreal Projects/TamagotchiGame/Binaries/IOS/Payload/TamagotchiGame.app/AppIcon40x40@2x~ipad.png
LogPlayLevel:   /Users/bariscavusoglu/Documents/Unreal Projects/TamagotchiGame/Binaries/IOS/Payload/TamagotchiGame.app/AppIcon76x76~ipad.png
LogPlayLevel:   /Users/bariscavusoglu/Documents/Unreal Projects/TamagotchiGame/Binaries/IOS/Payload/TamagotchiGame.app/AppIcon76x76@2x~ipad.png
LogPlayLevel:   /Users/bariscavusoglu/Documents/Unreal Projects/TamagotchiGame/Binaries/IOS/Payload/TamagotchiGame.app/AppIcon83.5x83.5@2x~ipad.png
LogPlayLevel:   /Users/bariscavusoglu/Documents/Unreal Projects/TamagotchiGame/Binaries/IOS/Payload/TamagotchiGame.app/Assets.car
LogPlayLevel:   /Users/bariscavusoglu/Documents/Unreal Projects/TamagotchiGame/Intermediate/IOS/Resources/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist
LogPlayLevel:   UPL Init: None
LogPlayLevel:   Generating and uploading Crashlytics Data
LogPlayLevel:   Deploying TamagotchiGame IOS Development...
LogPlayLevel:   UPL Init: None
LogPlayLevel:   Total build time: 205.64 seconds (Local executor: 109.81 seconds)
LogPlayLevel: Took 210.370288s to run mono, ExitCode=0
LogPlayLevel: ********** BUILD COMMAND COMPLETED **********
LogPlayLevel: Completed Launch On Stage: Build Task, Time: 249.747523
LogPlayLevel: ********** STAGE COMMAND STARTED **********
LogPlayLevel: Creating UE4CommandLine.txt
LogPlayLevel: Creating Staging Manifest...
LogPlayLevel: CookPlat IOS, this IOSPlatform
LogPlayLevel: UPL Init: None
LogPlayLevel: Cleaning Stage Directory: /Users/bariscavusoglu/Documents/Unreal Projects/TamagotchiGame/Saved/StagedBuilds/IOS
LogPlayLevel: Copying NonUFSFiles to staging directory: /Users/bariscavusoglu/Documents/Unreal Projects/TamagotchiGame/Saved/StagedBuilds/IOS
LogPlayLevel: Copying DebugFiles to staging directory: /Users/bariscavusoglu/Documents/Unreal Projects/TamagotchiGame/Saved/StagedBuilds/IOS
LogPlayLevel: Copying UFSFiles to staging directory: /Users/bariscavusoglu/Documents/Unreal Projects/TamagotchiGame/Saved/StagedBuilds/IOS
LogPlayLevel: Running: mono "/Users/Shared/Epic Games/UE_4.18/Engine/Binaries/DotNET/IOS/DeploymentServer.exe" Backup -file "/Users/bariscavusoglu/Documents/Unreal Projects/TamagotchiGame/Saved/StagedBuilds/IOS/Manifest_UFSFiles_IOS.txt" -file "/Users/bariscavusoglu/Documents/Unreal Projects/TamagotchiGame/Saved/StagedBuilds/IOS/Manifest_NonUFSFiles_IOS.txt"
 -device 7e22d78c455720c3ea44c00417ec407f80a16c6b -bundle com.bariscavusoglu.
LogPlayLevel:   [deploy] Created deployment server.
LogPlayLevel:   [DD] Trying to connect to mobile device running iOS ...
LogPlayLevel:   [DD] Mobile Device 'Baris???s iPhone' connected
LogPlayLevel:   Failed to connect to bundle 'com.bariscavusoglu.' with Unknown error 0xE80000B7
LogPlayLevel:   [DD]  ... File to be written '/Users/bariscavusoglu/Documents/Unreal Projects/TamagotchiGame/Saved/StagedBuilds/IOS\Baris???s iPhone_Manifest_UFSFiles_IOS.txt'
LogPlayLevel:   [DD]  ... File to be written '/Users/bariscavusoglu/Documents/Unreal Projects/TamagotchiGame/Saved/StagedBuilds/IOS\Baris???s iPhone_Manifest_NonUFSFiles_IOS.txt'
LogPlayLevel:   [DD]  ... Error: Failed to connect to bundle 'com.bariscavusoglu.'
LogPlayLevel:   [DD]
LogPlayLevel:   Exiting.
LogPlayLevel: Took 3.167487s to run mono, ExitCode=1
LogPlayLevel: ********** STAGE COMMAND COMPLETED **********
LogPlayLevel: ********** PACKAGE COMMAND STARTED **********
LogPlayLevel: Package /Users/bariscavusoglu/Documents/Unreal Projects/TamagotchiGame/TamagotchiGame.uproject
LogPlayLevel: UPL Init: None
LogPlayLevel: Project: /Users/bariscavusoglu/Documents/Unreal Projects/TamagotchiGame/TamagotchiGame_IOS.xcworkspace
LogPlayLevel: Running: mono "/Users/Shared/Epic Games/UE_4.18/Engine/Binaries/DotNET/UnrealBuildTool.exe" -XcodeProjectFiles -project="/Users/bariscavusoglu/Documents/Unreal Projects/TamagotchiGame/TamagotchiGame.uproject" -platforms=IOS -game -nointellisense -IOSdeployonly -ignorejunk -nocreatestub -NoHotReload -ignorejunk
LogPlayLevel:   Discovering modules, targets and source code for project...
LogPlayLevel:   Writing project files... 0%33%67%100%
LogPlayLevel:   Writing project files... 0%33%67%100%
LogPlayLevel:   Writing project files... 0%33%67%100%
LogSlate: Took 0.012457 seconds to synchronously load lazily loaded font '../../../Engine/Content/SlateDebug/Fonts/LastResort.ttf' (5269K)
LogSlate: Took 0.013482 seconds to synchronously load lazily loaded font '../../../Engine/Content/Slate/Fonts/DroidSansFallback.ttf' (3848K)
LogPlayLevel: Took 48.398044s to run mono, ExitCode=0
LogPlayLevel: Running: /usr/bin/env UBT_NO_POST_DEPLOY=true /usr/bin/xcrun xcodebuild build -workspace "/Users/bariscavusoglu/Documents/Unreal Projects/TamagotchiGame/TamagotchiGame_IOS.xcworkspace" -scheme 'TamagotchiGame' -configuration "Development" -destination generic/platform=iOS -sdk iphoneos CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="iPhone Developer: bronom@hotmail.com (B
4QB927267)" PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER=67a2a925-9aa8-42a9-a9e7-34018f3079f3
LogPlayLevel:   Build settings from command line:
LogPlayLevel:       CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = iPhone Developer: bronom@hotmail.com (B4QB927267)
LogPlayLevel:       PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER = 67a2a925-9aa8-42a9-a9e7-34018f3079f3
LogPlayLevel:       SDKROOT = iphoneos11.2
LogPlayLevel:   2018-01-04 13:28:03.459 xcodebuild[15482:142782] +dataWithFirstBytes:1024 ofFile:"/Users/bariscavusoglu/Documents/Unreal Projects/TamagotchiGame/Config/DefaultEditor.ini" failed, errno = 2
LogPlayLevel:   2018-01-04 13:28:03.992 xcodebuild[15482:142825]  DTDeviceKit: deviceType from 7e22d78c455720c3ea44c00417ec407f80a16c6b was NULL
LogPlayLevel:   2018-01-04 13:28:08.835 xcodebuild[15482:142782] +dataWithFirstBytes:1024 ofFile:"/Users/Shared/Epic Games/UE_4.18/Engine/Config/BaseEditorLayout.ini" failed, errno = 2
LogPlayLevel:   2018-01-04 13:28:09.622 xcodebuild[15482:142782] +dataWithFirstBytes:1024 ofFile:"/Users/Shared/Epic Games/UE_4.18/Engine/Plugins/Experimental/AlembicImporter/Source/ThirdParty/Alembic/alembic/houdini/SOP_AlembicIn/OPalembic/Object_1alembicarchive/Help" failed, errno = 2
LogPlayLevel:   2018-01-04 13:28:09.632 xcodebuild[15482:142782] +dataWithFirstBytes:1024 ofFile:"/Users/Shared/Epic Games/UE_4.18/Engine/Plugins/Experimental/AlembicImporter/Source/ThirdParty/Alembic/alembic/houdini/SOP_AlembicIn/OPalembic/Object_1alembicxform/Help" failed, errno = 2
LogPlayLevel:   2018-01-04 13:28:11.068 xcodebuild[15482:142782] +dataWithFirstBytes:1024 ofFile:"/Users/Shared/Epic Games/UE_4.18/Engine/Plugins/Experimental/AlembicImporter/Source/ThirdParty/Alembic/hdf5/tools/testfiles/tmulti-g.h5" failed, errno = 2
LogPlayLevel:   2018-01-04 13:28:11.120 xcodebuild[15482:142782] +dataWithFirstBytes:1024 ofFile:"/Users/Shared/Epic Games/UE_4.18/Engine/Plugins/Experimental/AlembicImporter/Source/ThirdParty/Alembic/hdf5/tools/testfiles/tnoddlfile.ddl" failed, errno = 2
LogPlayLevel:   2018-01-04 13:28:11.266 xcodebuild[15482:142782] +dataWithFirstBytes:1024 ofFile:"/Users/Shared/Epic Games/UE_4.18/Engine/Plugins/Experimental/AlembicImporter/Source/ThirdParty/Alembic/hdf5/tools/testfiles/twithddlfile.ddl" failed, errno = 2
LogPlayLevel:   2018-01-04 13:28:18.439 xcodebuild[15482:142795]  iPhoneConnect: ## Unable to mount developer disk image, (Error Domain=com.apple.dtdevicekit Code=-402652958 "Development cannot be enabled while your device is locked." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Development cannot be enabled while your device is locked., com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace
=(
LogPlayLevel:     0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001116c5fed DTDKCreateNSError + 113
LogPlayLevel:     1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001116c6831 DTDK_AMDErrorToNSError + 1135
LogPlayLevel:     2   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000111707441 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken mountDeveloperDiskImage:withError:] + 782
LogPlayLevel:     3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000111707cf8 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken mountDeveloperDiskImageWithError:] + 488
LogPlayLevel:     4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x00000001115eb250 __37-[DVTiOSDevice(Connect) hasConnected]_block_invoke_2 + 133
LogPlayLevel:     5   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000105d28b63 __DVTDispatchGroupAsync_block_invoke + 806
LogPlayLevel:     6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff7aa0f591 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
LogPlayLevel:     7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff7aa07d50 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
LogPlayLevel:     8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff7aa1aef5 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 599
LogPlayLevel:     9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff7aa126cb _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 703
LogPlayLevel:     10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff7aa09941 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 515
LogPlayLevel:     11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff7aa096ed _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 101
LogPlayLevel:     12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff7accc1ca _pthread_wqthread + 1387
LogPlayLevel:     13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff7accbc4d start_wqthread + 13
LogPlayLevel:   ), NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Please unlock your device and reattach. (0xE80000E2)., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Please unlock your device and reattach. (0xE80000E2).}) {
LogPlayLevel:       NSLocalizedDescription = "Development cannot be enabled while your device is locked.";
LogPlayLevel:       NSLocalizedFailureReason = "Please unlock your device and reattach. (0xE80000E2).";
LogPlayLevel:       NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion = "Please unlock your device and reattach. (0xE80000E2).";
LogPlayLevel:       "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
LogPlayLevel:     0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001116c5fed DTDKCreateNSError + 113
LogPlayLevel:     1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001116c6831 DTDK_AMDErrorToNSError + 1135
LogPlayLevel:     2   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000111707441 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken mountDeveloperDiskImage:withError:] + 782
LogPlayLevel:     3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000111707cf8 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken mountDeveloperDiskImageWithError:] + 488
LogPlayLevel:     4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x00000001115eb250 __37-[DVTiOSDevice(Connect) hasConnected]_block_invoke_2 + 133
LogPlayLevel:     5   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000105d28b63 __DVTDispatchGroupAsync_block_invoke + 806
LogPlayLevel:     6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff7aa0f591 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
LogPlayLevel:     7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff7aa07d50 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
LogPlayLevel:     8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff7aa1aef5 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 599
LogPlayLevel:     9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff7aa126cb _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 703
LogPlayLevel:     10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff7aa09941 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 515
LogPlayLevel:     11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff7aa096ed _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 101
LogPlayLevel:     12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff7accc1ca _pthread_wqthread + 1387
LogPlayLevel:     13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff7accbc4d start_wqthread + 13
LogPlayLevel:   );
LogPlayLevel:   }
LogPlayLevel:   === BUILD TARGET TamagotchiGame OF PROJECT TamagotchiGame WITH CONFIGURATION Development ===
LogPlayLevel:   Check dependencies
LogPlayLevel:   Code Signing Error: Signing certificate is invalid. Signing certificate "iPhone Developer: bronom@hotmail.com (B4QB927267)", serial number "1CD4670282940E26", is not valid for code signing. It may have been revoked or expired.
LogPlayLevel:   Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 11.2'
LogPlayLevel:   ** BUILD FAILED **
LogPlayLevel:   The following build commands failed:
LogPlayLevel:     Check dependencies
LogPlayLevel:   (1 failure)
LogPlayLevel: Took 19.987584s to run env, ExitCode=65
LogPlayLevel: ERROR: CodeSign Failed
LogPlayLevel:        (see /Users/bariscavusoglu/Library/Logs/Unreal Engine/LocalBuildLogs/UAT_Log.txt for full exception trace)
LogPlayLevel: AutomationTool exiting with ExitCode=32 (Error_FailedToCodeSign)
LogPlayLevel: Completed Launch On Stage: Deploy Task, Time: 82.563784
LogPlayLevel: RunUAT ERROR: AutomationTool was unable to run successfully.
PackagingResults: Error: Launch failed! Failed to Code Sign
```

Comment: can anyone help me with this???

Comment: As you can see in the log: " Code Signing Error: Signing certificate is invalid. Signing certificate ...  is not valid for code signing. It may have been revoked or expired."

Comment: Hello Pavel, Thanks for your reply.
It is not expired. I recently created a new certificate and a provisioning profile. When I enable a non-default plugin I get the following error.

LogPlayLevel: ERROR: CodeSign Failed

LogPlayLevel: RunUAT ERROR: AutomationTool was unable to run successfully.

PackagingResults: Error: Launch failed! Failed to Code Sign